# How get dynamic id of image in grid and show div on hover of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```
var imgRole = "grvMyRoles_ctl05_imgMyRoleDetail";
    var res = imgRole.substr(11, 5);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var offsetY = -110;
    var offsetX = -370;

    $("#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_imgMyRoleDetail").hover(function(e) {
        $("#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_divMyRoleDetails").fadeIn(400);
        $("#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_divMyRoleDetails").css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
    }, function() {
         $("#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_divMyRoleDetails").hide();
    });

    $("#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_imgMyRoleDetail").mousemove(function(e) {
        $("#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_divMyRoleDetails").css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
    });
});
```

This working correctly with static id. Here I am passing "grvMyRoles_ctl05_imgMyRoleDetail" as static image id which is present in GridView. And when I am hovering over it, it should show dynamic div with contents. Here I am passing "#grvMyRoles_" + res + "_divMyRoleDetails" as static div(as 'res' here remains constant for ids of both image and div)
But I want show dynamic div content on hover effect of dynamic image.

Please help.

Comment: Use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net webforms (as i see from your code) try to use `<% grvMyRoles.ClientID %>` instead of substring.

```
var imgRoleIdSelector = '#' + <%= grvMyRoles.ClientID %> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    var offsetY = -110;
    var offsetX = -370;

    $(imgRoleIdSelector).hover(function(e) {
        $(imgRoleIdSelector).fadeIn(400);
        $(imgRoleIdSelector).css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
    }, function() {
         $(imgRoleIdSelector).hide();
    });

    $(imgRoleIdSelector).mousemove(function(e) {
        $(imgRoleIdSelector).css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
    });
});
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx